# Moving a Subversion repository to another server

Tags: svn, backup, restore

I have a server that hosts my Subversion code base. That server is currently a [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) box, and my IT administrator wants to update it to [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008).

This means that I'm going to need to move my Subversion repository while the server gets built up and was wondering what the best practices are for moving the repository to a new server.

It seems like, looking online, the recommended way is to use:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > repository-name.dmp
```

And then use:

```
svnadmin create repository-name
svnadmin load repository-name< repository-name.dmp
```

To import the repository.

Does the method above seem like the best approach?

Comment: That's how I do it . . .

Comment: it's the "recommended way", so why do you doubt that it's a good approach? what does "best" mean, anyway?

Comment: Are you looking for a shorter version?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, dumping and loading the repository is a way to go. Copying the repository folder directly is a viable option if, and only if, you are certain nobody will be accessing the repository while the copy process is in progress (or you can do a "hot copy" of the repository, which can handle these cases in a safe manner).

You will also need to either re-checkout all your working copies, or use the **svn switch** command, which merely rewrites URLs. A more convenient way is to use TortoiseSVN's **Relocate** command, which reduces the risk of making a mistake during the relocation process.

Comment: Thanks,

Actually, it should be good with the relocate because the server it's moving to will be the same server IP as where it currently lives.

Comment: Thanks,  I struggled a little with direct copy because I didn't have my SVNServe root set correctly, but once I did it seems like the direct copy worked great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

My restore scripts are like this:

```
svnadmin create repository-name --fs-type fsfs
svnadmin load   repository-name --force-uuid < repository-name.dmp
```

The first line ensures the repository uses the `FSFS` backend (which is recommended by many sources, including this one: [How FSFS is Better](http://web.mit.edu/ghudson/info/fsfs), and AFAIK newer versions of Subversion use it as default). [FSFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion#FSFS) is the name of a Subversion filesystem implementation.

The second lines keeps the UUID of the repository, for an easier transition (without `--force-uuid` switch, the working copy relocation will fail).

Some links:

- [Subversion admin - moving repository around](http://rextang.net/blogs/work/archive/2006/05/03/3697.aspx)
- [Moving a Subversion Repository to Another Server](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/665.cfm)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to move the repository; that way you can transfer all the data without the need to take the 'old' repository down. This is also the only way I know of to get your data from hosted environments, where you don't have shell access or access to dumping the repository.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative:

use svnrdump.
http://www.crowbarsolutions.com/backing-up-restoring-a-remote-svn-repository/

"You’re going to need a a tool called svnrdump. As described by Apache, “svnrdump replicates the functionality of svnadmin dump and svnadmin load, but works on remote repositories, instead of needing administrator (local filesystem) access to the source or target repository.”

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the File System type repository, you can just literally take the folder containing your repository and move it.  If you are changing servers, then chances are you will need to change the location that your local working directory looks for the repository by using the 'Relocate' command.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use:

```
svnadmin hotcopy path/to/your_current_directory /path/to/your_destination_directory
```