# How to move SVN repository in hard disk

Tags: svn, repository

I have an SVN repository on my hard disk in a directory like:

```
/home/Desktop/path/to/old_repo
```

But I need to move this repository to another place

```
/home/Downloads/path/to/new_repo
```

an remove all the files in the old directory. I tried using `svnadmin dump`, then `svn create` and `svn load`, but when I remove the `old_repo` folder they stop working. In fact, they do not contain any piece of code and just give me some information about `log` and `status`.

How can I move this repository to a completely different location having it work independently (I want to remove the old one)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion - Move Repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360758/subversion-move-repository)

Comment: @bahrep I explained in my question that I have tried that one, even I have an answer in the question that you are referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `file:///` access to repository, you can

- Move directory to new location
- Relocate all Working Copy in order to reflect new URL

If you use any network-type access (`svn://` or `http://`) to repository, you can

- Move directory to new location
- Change settings of used daemon in order to reflect new physical location of repository

Comment: I'm on the file service. Should I `svn copy` or just copy that working directory?

Comment: relocate isn't a command, I used it as an option for copy but it didn't work

Comment: I got it, I did not MOVE the main repository, I always copied the directory to another location, because I was afraid to loose data ;)

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Stop all services and anything that might write to the repository.

Step 2. Copy (as in OS cp or drag and drop folder) the repository directory to the new location.

Step 3: Update the service's configuration to refer to the new repository (eg Apache conf, svnserver conf or VisualSVN GUI).

Step 4: restart the service and let people carry on using it.

There's nothing special about a SVN server repository, its a self-contained directory with normal files in it. There's no registry or /etc conf files that need updating. YTou do need to update whatever access system you use to get at it (eg http or svn protocols go through a server, either apache or svnserve) so you need to tell them the new location, but that's it.